# Why can't I return a Task<IEnumerable<out T>> without making my method async and using await

Tags: c#, arrays, async-await, task, ienumerable

Currently I have a method with the signature `public Task<IEnumerable<Descriptor>> GetAllDescriptors()` where `Descriptor` is a public class I created. I then have various tasks that I call within this method like so:

```
var allDescriptors = Task.WhenAll(GetMovieDescriptorAsync, GetSongDescriptorAsync);
```

Since `GetMovieDescriptorAsync` & `GetSongDescriptorAsync` both return `Task<Descriptor>` I know that the variable type of `allDescriptors` is `Task<Descriptor[]>` which is great. However if I try `return allDescriptors` I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Descriptor[]>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Descriptor>>'
```

However, if I change the method signature to `public async Task<IEnumerable<Descriptor>> GetAllDescriptors()` and then I try `return await allDescriptors` it works and I get the desired `<IEnumerable<CompletionInfo>` in the calling function:

```
var descriptors = await GetAllDescriptors();
```

Why is that and how can I return the expected `IEnumerable<Descriptor>` without having to use async and await?

Comment: Please show the actual code that fails to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (and solution) you are describing is [**`covariance`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). [`IEnumerable<out T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-7.0) is a covariant interface, which means you can assign `IEnumerable<string>` into `IEnumerable<object>`.

However, [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-7.0) **IS NOT** covariant. That means you can't return a more specific object in place of a generic definition (if you've `Task<object>`, you can't return `Task<string>`).

Now, adding `async` and `await` makes the compiler treat this a bit differently. Simplifying, `async` cancels out the `Task` declaration, so it returns the `TResult`. And if you have a method `object Foo()`, you can use `return ""` inside this method. Because the return type of a method is always covariant.

To summarize, `async Task<TResult>` is similar of `TResult`, so you can return more specific objects this way. However, `Task<TResult>` is a non-covariant type, so you have to return exactly the type specified.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with covariance. The issue is that `Task.WhenAll` takes as input an array of tasks, and returns a task with an array of results. The result type in question is `IEnumerable<Descriptor>` so, `Task.WhenAll` is taking two tasks that each return an `IEnumerable<Descriptor>` and returning a task that returns an array of `IEnumerable<Descriptor>`s